# How to put page number into existing PDF using perl

Tags: perl, pdf

Could you please help me to solve this issue?

I want to add page numbers to PDFs using perl. I tried this with the PDF::Reuse module but this is not working well. Please check and do the needful...

Comment: @Spaceghost: It's the new dance craze. Do the needful!

Answer (score 1):

I've found a nice artical here:
http://www.perl.com/pub/2007/09/20/pdf-processing-with-perl.html

and here is the relevant exapmle:

```
  # file: examples/sample-numbers.pl
  use PDF::Reuse;
  use strict;

  my $n = 1;

  prFile('examples/sample-numbers.pdf');

  while (1) {
     prText(550, 40, $n++);
     last unless prSinglePage('sample-letters.pdf');
  }

  prEnd();
```

If this is the way you did it and it didn't work, adding your code can be helpful.

Hope I helped.

Lior

Answer (score 0):

The module [PDF::API2::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~redtree/PDF-API2-Simple-1.1.4u/lib/PDF/API2/Simple.pm) also lets you edit PDF files. You can select the font you want and find the location through trial and error on the resulting page.